# PHP: Function within a function then include with internal functions

Tags: php, class, function, templates

I have tested the following and it doesn't work. Is there a similar way of achieving this?

**A compiling class which formulates a template**:

```
private function include_header () {
    function _metadata () {
        // Metadata compiler
        return $metadata;
    }
    include (path . "header.php");
}
```

**header.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
        _metadata ();
    ?>
    <title>Hello Stackoverflow!</title>
</head>
<body>
    ...
```

The `_metadata ();` function is only available within the `include_header ();` function - nowhere else in the class. I don't want to have to write `$this->_metadata ();` in the template file only `_metadata ();`. Is that achievable?

Alternatively one could create an external file, for example `functions.php` which has the underscore functions specifically for the template - but I'd much rather see if the original query is possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa.

So, essentially, you can't do what you're trying to do. `_metadata` will always be a global function if it is defined with the `function _metadata() {` syntax. The normal function syntax only supports global functions.

*However*, PHP 5.3 introduces something called ["anonymous functions"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). These can be assigned to a variable. Since variables *can* be scoped to a function scope (they are only global if you explicitly say so), you can limit them in this way.

For instance:

```
$_metadata = function() {
    // Metadata compiler
    return $metadata;
};
```

This could then be called in `header.php` with:

```
<?php $_metadata(); ?>
```

Note that this *is* less stable: it is, for instance, possible to redefine the variable to be a different anonymous function – or indeed not a function at all. The safest solution, ultimately, is to use a templating language that solves these issues for you. If not, you can either accept that you'll have to use global functions or anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define nested function in PHP. I mean, you can, but there's no purpose since they'll have a global scope and therefore they will be callable from any point of the script.

But you actually don't need to define a `_metadata()` function, you can just execute all the function logic inside `include_header()` and then store everything in the variable `$metadata`, which will be printed in the include with a simple `<?php echo $metadata; ?>`.

If you really need to define a function you can use the function [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) or (just for PHP > 5.3) an [`anonymous function`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Since they will be encapsulated inside a variable, which has a function scope, they won't be available outside.

Comment: I am trying to avoid `echo`, `print` etc. I want to use a function.

Comment: @Alex you have to use `echo`, `print` etc. anyway, what you currently have will do nothing.

Comment: I meant, outside the function. Of course `echo`, `print` will be inside the function. Thank you nonetheless :)